# Excel Todo List

Tags: vba, excel

I have an Excel file that purposes as a task list. It looks like this:
[image: Excel Image]

I want it set up so that when I switch the status to "Done", the entry is removed to the table and displayed on a second sheet with all the other "Done" entries.

I have had some success using a macro to automatically update a filter that hides the entry from the table, but do not know how to copy the row onto a new sheet.

Comment: There are many duplicates of similar questions; I've just picked the first one that looked close. If you can't manipulate the answers there to what you want, ask a specific question here, instead of a generic request for code.

Answer (score -1):

how about you try something like this. Something i came across a year ago and changed it some[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wYMG7.jpg)

```
Sub MoveRow(DL As Long)
Dim A As Worksheet

Dim d As Worksheet
Dim P As Worksheet

Dim From As String
Dim To As String
Dim OK As String
Dim S As String

Dim F As Long
Dim T As Long
Dim AL As Long
Dim FL As Long

Dim x As Integer

'find sheet 
Set P = Worksheets("YourSheet") 'i Call this sheet "parameters" where I put my defined parameters. This sheet defines all actions (see pic)
S = P.Cells(4, 2)
Set d = Worksheets(S)
S = P.Cells(5, 2)
Set A = Worksheets(S)

' cloumn from/T0
From = P.Cells(2, 2)
To = P.Cells(3, 2)
F = d.Range(from & "1").Column
T = d.Range(To & "1").Column
AL = A.UsedRange.Rows.Count + 1

For x = F To T
A.Cells(AL, x) = d.Cells(DL, x)
Next

'Delete row
d.Range(from & DL & ":" & Til & DL).Select
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
d.Range(from & DL).Select
End Sub
```